# Prohibition in Japanese depending on level of formality

Tags: verbs, conjugations, formality

I have learnt two variants for prohibition:
-ちゃだめ
-ではいけません
depending on the level of formality…

But does an intermediate form of
-じゃいけない or 
-ではいけない

exist as well?

Comment: Note that ちゃだめ and ではいけません don't carry the same nuance as well, the formality isn't the only difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all combinations are possible. Taking 見る as an example, you can say all of the following (roughly in the descending order of formality):

- 見てはいけません。
- 見てはだめです。
- 見てはいけない。
- 見ちゃいけない。
- 見ちゃだめ(だ(よ))。

だめです may look like a weird combination of a colloquial word and the polite form, but it can happen when a teacher say "don't ..." to their students, for example.